# Making image percentage bigger in mobile version of my website

Tags: html, css, css-position

Nowadays I am taking some freelance jobs from the local stores in my country. I just wanted to make a general draft for that and I can manipulate it when I got a new job by changing color etc. :) Even though I am a newbie for this field it is good to get some little jobs.

However, I am troubling with responsive images. I am so happy that my image takes %50 on the full desktop page. It fits perfectly. But on the mobile page %50 is too small. I want it to take more % on the mobile-version page. I don't know if it is possible. I tried a media query, it did not work for this. I am gonna share my codepen link so could you guys look into that? Have a lovely day.

[Here is link for codepen.io](https://codepen.io/illuminoted/pen/BaKJZPG?editors=1100)

```
@media only screen and(max-width:700px) {
    img { 
        width:60%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A media query is an option but I think max-width works better.

```
img{
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

So now on desktop, it will be 1000px and if the screen gets too small it scales with the screen width.

Answer (score 3):

there is problem with space

```
@media only screen and (max-width:700px){
    img{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

Now the media query will work fine

Comment: This works too! :) I can't believe it just didn't adjust my page because of only "one space". :)